# enter path written in a file

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm writing a code with fortran and I have several different output saved in different directory.

During the Do cycle I saved the temporary PATH of the output in a file.txt

Now I'm trying to plot the results runtime, but I need to enter the PATH of the output to use allways the same gnuplot script.

I want to if is possibile from terminal (shell) to enter into the PATH written in file.txt, that is read the PATH from my file.txt and enter in PATH with cd command.

I tried with cat but nothing happends!

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several ways to do this, but the idea is always the same. How to use the output of cat ?
There are 2 possible syntax, with backquotes and with `$(command)`. I'll use the second one which is preferred (see [BashFAQ 82])

You can do it in one line

```
cd "$(cat file.txt)"
```

Or in two steps

```
path=$(cat file.txt)
cd "$path"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have resolved with the first solution!

Comment: Don't forget to mark one answer with the green V so that your question is marked as solved

Comment: ok now I have the same problem with ipython

Comment: Is possible to do the same think in Ipython, because the shell answer with an error!

Comment: f = open('file.txt')
path_to_output = f.read().strip() # strip to remove the spaces and new lines at the end and the beginning
os.chdir(path_to_output)

Comment: You quoted the one place where quotes aren't needed and failed to quote the places where they are needed. `$()` is preferred over backquotes (see [BashFAQ 82](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)), and lastly, avoid using [uppercase variable names](http://stackoverflow.com/a/673940/1524545). So `cd "$(cat file.txt)"` or `path=$(cat file.txt); cd "$path"`

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to cd into a directory written in a text file using the shell? If so, use the following:

```
cd $(cat /path/to/file.txt)
```